# How do you install a module in spyder anaconda?

Tags: module, image-registration

I'm trying to run some code in Spyder Anaconda. I thought it would be as simple as importing it as seen in the code but I get an error message:

> **ModuleNotFoundError:** No module named 'image_registration'

I know this means that image_registration isn't included in what Spyder already has but I cant quite figure out how to add it.

```
from image_registration import chi2_shift

from image_registration.fft_tools import shift
```

Comment: which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your Anaconda Scripts path (Default=C:\Users\userna**\Anaconda3\Scripts) to Environment Variables and open your command prompt and type
`pip.exe install module_name`In your case pip.exe install image_registration [To install module image Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgSRb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please tryout the below steps in anaconda prompt

```
1. conda create -n myenv
2. activate myenv
3. pip install image_registration
4. conda install spyder
5. spyder
```

If you have already installed image_registration package in an environment you can activate that environment and try to open spyder from the activated environment.